# adding color change in button of onclick function

Tags: javascript, html

so first of all, i'm completely new to coding world. have 0 base.
currently buliding a web controller for DAW(digital audio workstation) program called "reaper"

```
`<script src="main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
wwr_start();
function onSliderChanged(slider) {
    wwr_req(`SET/TRACK/${slider.id}/VOL/${slider.value}`);
}
function`your text` mutetrack(track) {
    wwr_req(`SET/TRACK/${track.id}/MUTE/-1`); 
}
</script>
body>
<input type="button" value="Judege MUTE" id="32" onclick="mutetrack(this);
       ">`
```

This is what one of my button script looks like, onlick fucntion of that button mute targetted (number in id section of input) track.
and i would like to add color changing option to it. by onclicking the button i want that button color to be changed into certain color and get back to normal status if clicked again. i tried numurous way, such as getElementsByTagName etc, perhaps i'm placing code into wrong section or so.
my friend who usually helps me with coding issue is away now so i'm all alone working through this.
please help me. thank you!

i can't remeber now, i have copy & paste numerous way that i searched on google. perhaps i've placed code in wrong order or place`your text`

Comment: The code is just a bunch of errors, please fix it to show what you really have. Inline listeners are bad, don't use them, add the listeners with [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead. Then in the listener, `event.target` will be the clicked button.

Answer (score 0):

I have just added a simple solution it is not complex too much you can easily learn this

```js
var sts = false

function myFunction() {
  sts = !sts
  if (sts) {
    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<button id='myDIV' onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```